# How do I use Mousekeys before I login into Win 7 Pro?

Tags: windows-7

I only use the keyboard to nagivate around when I'm logged-in but when I get logged off I have to find a mouse again cause Mousekeys doesn't work on the login screen.  Is there any way to use Mousekeys or just the keyboard to login?

Win 7 Pro.

Comment: Why not to use keyboard keys (such as Tab, Enter) to log in?